# Navigational tabs in winforms Mono overlaying each other

Tags: c#, winforms, mono

I have a winforms app that I'm running in Mac (Yosemite) on Mono (for .NET framework 4.5). The app uses navigational tabs (Home, Customers, Artists, Exhibitions, Products, Reports) to provide areas of different functionality. The issue is that the forms displayed in these tabs keep appearing overlaid on the form of the currently selected tab.

The below image shows what I mean. Here the form from the Products tab (which has the headings Title, Price, Category, Artist, Medium etc.) is overlaying the currently selected Home tab (which has the two labels you can see of Debtors and Customer Notes near the top). If the Customers tab was then to be clicked, this would stop this happening temporarily, but the issue might then reoccur when selecting another tab.

[image: products tab overlaying home tab]

This issue only seems to occur on Mac so must be a Mac Mono issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Its extremely difficult to see what you are getting at, I don't have a Mac but are screenshots (instead of camera pictures) difficult on Yosemite?

Comment: Sorry, it was an image from a not too tech savvy client. I've updated the original explanation to hopefully make it clearer.